# Can't get value through DOMDocument and getElementById() in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

This is my HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="serviceOK">Total</td>
    <td class="serviceOK">0d 0h 0m 0s</td>
    <td id="test" class="serviceOK">0.000%</td>
    <td class="serviceOK">0.000%</td>
</tr>
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
@$doc->loadHTML($report); //$report is actually my HTML code.
echo $doc->saveHTML(); //echoes everything successfully.

$run = $doc->getElementById('test');
echo $run; //echoes Nothing
var_dump($run); //echoes NULL
```

I'm using PHP [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse my HTML code and retrieve the value inside that element with id="test" but it doesn't echo anything. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: u can use jquery also .

Comment: try `$doc->getElementById('test')->tagName;` and see

Comment: @sharif - jquery has nothing to do with this. Zim3r is parsing it server side.

Comment: @joe Thanks but it returned the entire page not the element with test id.

Comment: @Rhea It returned an error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...`

Comment: thanks@Joe .i cant understand the problem :(

Comment: @joe, Did as you said and but unfortunately I see nothing again.

Comment: Do a `view source` and check what exactly is getting rendered

Comment: Thanks @Rhea, I did what you said and everything is fine.

Comment: [This Code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c5s-8pe) which runs successfully on PHPFiddle can't run on my webserver. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`$run` is a DOMElement object; you need to grab its nodeValue: `echo $run->nodeValue;`

Proof: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c5s-8pe

Edit: Since your `var_dump` is returning null, you need to check your HTML. It's not able to get parsed, and/or there are multiple ID's in the DOM with the same ID -- which shouldn't happen (ID's should be *unique*)

Comment: Then his issue is elsewhere.

Comment: +1 - it's difficult to tell what's wrong given the information in the question but it's likely to be duplicate IDs or something similar.

Comment: Thank you, I exactly tried your code on my webserver and I can't believe It gives me an error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/test.php on line 16 `

Comment: You tried everything exactly in that PHPFiddle link? What's your PHP Version?

Comment: Yes Exactly, PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2013 02:51:11)
with php-domxml-php4-php5 and php-xml installed.

Comment: Is there any specific configuration? because it doesn't work on my localhost neither.

Answer (score 1):

is your PHP code written after the html code? maybe it cannot find the element, because the script is running before the element is formed

Comment: oh, right. then maybe there is some problem in the quotes so the HTML is not parsed properly.

Comment: Yes It is, but I think here I have a problem on server. commented on Rob's post.